# Is it preferable to have GRUB2 installed on a HDD vs SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, grub2, ssd

My system has an internal 160Gb SSD + 1Tb HDD.
Win 7 is installed on the SSD and Ubuntu (2 versions) is installed on HDD.
I've been successful in installing Grub2 on SSD and able to boot all 3 OSs. I'm asking because of the write limits on SSD.

Answer (score 0):

If write limits are your concern, then Grub will be your least problem. It will write at most one sector per boot (for saving some settings, which is optional and configurable), while the operating system most certainly is going to write more than that.

Comment: So If I'm primarily using Ubuntu then there won't be many writes at all ... correct? Do you know of any other guidance I should investigate?

Comment: Not really. I quite simply don't really think it matters in any way whatsoever which drive you put Grub on. :)